# How can I verify if TOR relay is working

Tags: linux, networking, security, proxy, privacy

I am attempting to run a relay node on my Kali Linux VM. It appears like everything is working. I started it with systemctl and the service is active.

I looked up my public IP on

```
https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html
```

But it didn't show up. Is it working?

If not, then how can I further diagnose the problem... if any? I ran the following command

```
tshark -i eth0 | grep 11666
```

Traffic started flooding in. However, if I disable Tor and rerun the Wireshark command, I still get tons of traffic flooding in so I don't think Wireshark alone is a good indicator of success.

Here is my torrc file. And yes, I restarted tor via systemctl

```
Nickname myNiceRelay1111
ORPort 11666
DirPort 11667
ExitRelay 0
SocksPort 0
ControlSocket 0
ContactInfo operator@1111.com
```

Comment: Better post your question on **[TOR StackEx](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)**.